# pgfplots - Define a extra x tick for the x interaction of a regression line

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, ticks

I have a regression line of some points and need a `extra x tick` at the x interaction of this regression. I could just calculate the value and make the tick by `extra x ticks={x1}` but I have to make lots of different curves and I'd like to have a prototype, so I only have to create some .txt documents and the rest is made automaticly by Tex.

Is it possible by using the `\pgfplotstableregressiona` and `\pgfplotstableregressionb` terms?
Is there any solution like for example `extra x ticks=[-1 * \pgfplotstableregressionb / \pgfplotstableregressiona}` (Of course, this is not working...)

This is how it looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,every axis legend/.append style={%
        ,at={(0.03,0.97)}
        ,anchor=north west}
        }
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        ,width=10cm,height=10cm
        ,x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}
        ,xmin=0,xmax=0.6
        ,ymin=0,ymax=22 
        ,xlabel=Weg/mm, 
        ,ylabel=Kraft/N,
        ]
        \addplot+[%
            ,fill = blue
            ,mark = *
            ,mark options={solid}
            ,only marks
            ] table {%
                x       y
                0.400   18.096
                0.400   18.401
                0.400   17.767
                0.400   16.992
                0.400   16.399
                0.397   15.908
                0.392   15.440
                0.387   14.533
                0.382   13.258
                0.377   11.939      
                };
        \addlegendentry{Kraft-Weg-Kurve}
        \addplot [] table [%
            ,y={create col/linear regression}] {%
                x       y
                0.400   18.096
                0.400   18.401
                0.400   17.767
                0.400   16.992
                0.400   16.399
                0.397   15.908
                0.392   15.440
                0.387   14.533
                0.382   13.258
                0.377   11.939
                };  
        \addplot [draw,domain=0.25:0.5] (x,\pgfplotstableregressiona*x+\pgfplotstableregressionb);
        \addlegendentry{Regression {$\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=4, fixed zerofill]{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot \mathrm{t} \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=4, fixed zerofill]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}}  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out for a solution that works very well: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=26683&p=91610#p91609

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments by the OP himself.